# Javascript button click in another url

Tags: javascript, button, checkbox

There are url1 and url2. (url1 and url2 is in the same site. for example,
url1 = http://tcafe2a.com/community/free_talk; and url2 = http://tcafe2a.com/community/tv_talk;)

url2 has a checkbox and a button that I want to check and click.
url1 has a button that I made and when I click it then...

1. open window in url2.
2. check the checkbox.(located in url2)
3. click the button.(located in url2)

However, my button will only open a window with url2 and it will not check the checkbox nor click the button. Maybe the website isn't loaded yet?

I hope it doesn't open a window in url2 and just check the checkbox and click the button if it's possible. If that's impossible then teach me how to fix this so 1),2),3) will be executed in the right order, please.

My codes are...

```
function reply_del1() {
var button1 = document.createElement("button");
button1.innerHTML = "DeleteComments";

var body1 = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body1.appendChild(button1);

button1.addEventListener ("click", function() {

var url2 = "http://somesite12345.com/attendance/cmt.php";//1)
window.open(url2);

$('#check_all').trigger('click');//2)

document.getElementsByName("btn_delete")[0].click();//3)
});
}
```

Comment: If it is two different sites, this is something that browsers block. It counts as a Cross Site Script and can be used in attacks on users and websites. Solving this with javascript is generally the wrong solution. Depending on what you try to do, check if there are API calls to do this, otherwise maybe you can solve it using AutoHotKey/AutoIt?

Comment: In addition, your JS after `window.open()` is targeting the caller page, not the popup page.

Comment: I see. Is that mean, I have to make a button to run 1) and then make another button to run 2) and 3) when 1) is loaded?

Comment: These days you need a really good reason to resort to archaic popup windows. What, ultimately, are you trying to retrieve? What does checking the box and clicking the button actually *do*?

Comment: It a community website. Often times it sends me ads or unwanted alarms about other user's comments. I don't want to read them so I made a button to make it go away without looking at it.